# Why does object inside a protected method has implementation?

Tags: java, object

Its the method invokeBackend(String request, HashMap context) .

Why does it have an object named java.security.PrivilegedAction createController = new java.security.PrivilegedAction()
and it has an implementation ? I see it has a run() method which means its a thread.

1. Does the run method returns "controller"? It returns "controller" to what?
2. What kind of an implementation is this? An object having implementation code?
   3.Whats the primary use of implmentation of the method invokeBackend

   Also the object

java.security.PrivilegedAction processRequest = new java.security.PrivilegedAction()

Thanks a lot!

```
protected static String invokeBackend(String request, HashMap context)
        throws CommonModelException {

    if (request.equals("")) {
        return null;
    }

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("request: \r\n" + request);
    }

    Properties clientAuthenticationEnv = CommonProperties
            .getClientAuthenticationProperties();
    if (wccClientId == null) {
        wccClientId = clientAuthenticationEnv.getProperty(CLIENT_ID);
    }
    if (wccClientPassword == null) {
        wccClientPassword = clientAuthenticationEnv
                .getProperty(CLIENT_PASSWORD);
    }

    controllerHome = getControllerHome();
    String response = null;

    try {

        if (controllerHome == null) {
            throw new CommonModelException(ResourceBundleHelper.resolve(
                    CommonResourceBundleNames.COMMON_STRINGS,
                    LOG_REMOTE_EXCEPTION));
        }
        if (isWASImpl) {
            java.security.PrivilegedAction createController = new java.security.PrivilegedAction() {
                public Object run() {
                    Object controller = null;
                    try {
                        controller = controllerHome.create();
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        logger.error(ResourceBundleHelper.resolve(
                                CommonResourceBundleNames.COMMON_STRINGS,
                                LOG_REMOTE_EXCEPTION), e);
                    } catch (CreateException e) {
                        logger.error(ResourceBundleHelper.resolve(
                                CommonResourceBundleNames.COMMON_STRINGS,
                                LOG_FAIL_GET_EJB_INSTANCE), e);
                    }
                    return controller;
                }
            }; // PrivilegedAction

            validateSecurityToken();
            final DWLServiceController controller = (DWLServiceController) WSSubject
                    .doAs(subject, createController);

            final String req = request;
            final HashMap cxt = context;

            java.security.PrivilegedAction processRequest = new java.security.PrivilegedAction() {
                public Object run() {
                    Object response = null;
                    try {
                        response = (String) controller.processRequest(cxt,
                                req);
                    } catch (com.dwl.base.exception.DWLResponseException e) {
                        response = e.getLocalizedMessage();
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        logger.error(ResourceBundleHelper.resolve(
                                CommonResourceBundleNames.COMMON_STRINGS,
                                LOG_REMOTE_EXCEPTION), e);
                    }
                    return response;
                }
            }; // PrivilegedAction

            validateSecurityToken();
            response = (String) WSSubject.doAs(subject, processRequest);
        } else {
            // DWLServiceController controller = controllerHome.create();
            // response = (String) controller.processRequest(context,
            // request);

            java.security.PrivilegedAction createController = new java.security.PrivilegedAction() {
                public Object run() {
                    Object controller = null;
                    try {
                        controller = controllerHome.create();
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        logger.error(ResourceBundleHelper.resolve(
                                CommonResourceBundleNames.COMMON_STRINGS,
                                LOG_REMOTE_EXCEPTION), e);
                    } catch (CreateException e) {
                        logger.error(ResourceBundleHelper.resolve(
                                CommonResourceBundleNames.COMMON_STRINGS,
                                LOG_FAIL_GET_EJB_INSTANCE), e);
                    }
                    return controller;
                }
            }; // PrivilegedAction
            
            //reflection invoke to avoid compile dependency on weblogic library
            ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            Class securityClazz = cl.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("weblogic.security.Security");
            Method runAs = securityClazz.getMethod("runAs", new Class[]{Subject.class, java.security.PrivilegedAction.class});
            final DWLServiceController controller = (DWLServiceController) runAs.invoke(securityClazz, new Object[]{subject, createController});
            //final DWLServiceController controller = (DWLServiceController) Security.runAs(subject, createController);

            final String req = request;
            final HashMap cxt = context;

            java.security.PrivilegedAction processRequest = new java.security.PrivilegedAction() {
                public Object run() {
                    Object response = null;
                    try {
                        response = (String) controller.processRequest(cxt,
                                req);
                    } catch (com.dwl.base.exception.DWLResponseException e) {
                        response = e.getLocalizedMessage();
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        logger.error(ResourceBundleHelper.resolve(
                                CommonResourceBundleNames.COMMON_STRINGS,
                                LOG_REMOTE_EXCEPTION), e);
                    }
                    return response;
                }
            }; // PrivilegedAction

            response = (String)runAs.invoke(securityClazz, subject, processRequest);
            //response = (String) Security.runAs(subject, processRequest);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        response = e.getLocalizedMessage();
        // for non IBM WebSphere Server, we have one more chance to redo
        // lookup for EJB server restart, clear the session first
        controllerHome = getControllerHome();

        if (controllerHome == null) {
            throw new CommonModelException(ResourceBundleHelper.resolve(
                    CommonResourceBundleNames.COMMON_STRINGS,
                    LOG_REMOTE_EXCEPTION));
        }

        try {

            DWLServiceController controller = controllerHome.create();
            response = (String) controller.processRequest(context, request);
        } catch (DWLResponseException e1) {
            response = e1.getLocalizedMessage();
        } catch (RemoteException e1) {
            logger.error(ResourceBundleHelper.resolve(
                    CommonResourceBundleNames.COMMON_STRINGS,
                    LOG_REMOTE_EXCEPTION), e1);
            throw new CommonModelException(e1);
        } catch (CreateException e1) {
            logger.error(ResourceBundleHelper.resolve(
                    CommonResourceBundleNames.COMMON_STRINGS,
                    LOG_FAIL_GET_EJB_INSTANCE), e1);
            throw new CommonModelException(e1);
        }
    }

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("response: \r\n" + response);
    }

    return response;
}
```

Comment: you want us to explain ALL that code? Step by step? Not happening.

Comment: If you're a novice programmer, you shouldn't be doing anything to that kind of code. You should be reading tutorials and learning the basics.

Comment: Nathan , Thank you so much for the links. I just checked anonymous classes and the link you provided about the security api.

So the processrequest and createcontroller are anonymous classes which are expressions. and I see the connection to the code in their usage. thanks a lot for the help

Comment: redFIVE , Kayaman thanks for the advice but I'm a proficient Filenet developer, and a basic java developer. I'm learning from the people who help me in this forum and other paths. I would have definitely helped anyone who asked any question if I were proficient in it. 

Nathan I don't see your answer anymore Please reply back so that I can rate it well. It helped a lot. Thanks again pal! Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration you're looking at is a local variable initialized to reference an instance of an anonymous inner class. The class implemented is [PrivilegedAction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/PrivilegedAction.html). The syntax is used when you want to create a one-off implementation of an interface or class that you don't intend to use elsewhere, so there's no point in giving it a name. The code implements the run method from the interface and creates an object implementing that interface, that it assigns to the local variable.

The run method returns a controller object to whoever calls run on it. That isn't shown here, it's passed in as one of the arguments to the runAs method call on this line:

```
final DWLServiceController controller = (DWLServiceController) runAs.invoke(
    securityClazz, new Object[]{subject, createController});
```

where the code used reflection to look up the runAs method on the class `weblogic.security.Security`.

Comment: It helped a lot Nathan. The two anonymous inner classes processrequest and createcontroller are implemented from the interface PrivilegedAction which has the run method declaration.

This is because it's only implemented once and never again. One followup question regarding this. Can this be considered a singleton pattern of implementation?

Comment: user3641003: i wouldn't think so. singleton means you enforce having a single instance that multiple things call. here only 1 thing is going to use it. maybe strategy pattern fits better.